# Where can I find lists of theorems that have been verified?

Tags: mathematics, applications, reference-request

I recall many years ago seeing a very large and well-interlinked (by computer) list of verified results starting from base assumptions and leading to all sorts of things that naive me did not expect computers to be able to handle e.g. measure theory. I don't recall what software was used, and certainly don't see any sort of link on e.g. https://leanprover.github.io/.

Where can I find these types of lists?

Comment: This should be a wiki question/answer as no answer will be comprehensive.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I have just flagged for this (I presume that's how it works here too)

Answer (score 23):

The Lean community maintains several of such lists:

- https://leanprover-community.github.io/undergrad.html keeps track of which part of a French undergrad curriculum have been added to mathlib
- https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib-overview.html is a general overview of the contents of mathlib, listing "well-known" definitions/theorems that have been formalized.
- https://leanprover-community.github.io/100.html keeps track of which of [Freek's 100 theorem](https://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Efreek/100/) list have been verified in Lean
- https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/ is not really a list, but it is online documentation of all results in mathlib (and Lean core).

Comment: Thank you! The immediate takeaway for me is that I should have checked the community page. I suppose did not because I wanted to find information by 'lurking' rather than ask a newbie question.

Answer (score 21):

Freek Wiedijk maintains a list of 100 theorems, and pointers to formalizations in many different systems: [https://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/100/](https://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Efreek/100/)

The 100 theorems on the list were chosen a long time ago (and not by Freek). Some people think they are not a great selection of "100 important results in mathematics" but nevertheless, this list has become a sort of de facto benchmark for theorem provers and their libraries.

Answer (score 18):

Mizar publishes them quarterly in their journal [*Formalized Mathematics*](http://mizar.org/fm/).

Comment: +1, this certainly fits what I was looking for. Mizar itself sounds amazing and I'm surprised it can already be used for a journal.

Comment: "already" is a bit misleading here. As of now Mizar has served as the basis for the Journal of Formalized Mathematics for more than 30 years.

Answer (score 17):

[Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/index.html) has such an extensive interlinked library.

A list of theorems in metamath is available [here](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems.html).

Comment: Ah, this is the list I stumbled upon many years before! For instance here is [the Lebesgue integral.](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems234.html#mm23383s) Although, in hindsight there are many other lists such as the other answers. In other SEs I would consider the tag [big-list] / flag to make comm wiki, any thoughts..?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 17):

**Coq** has an official [Coq `opam` repository](https://github.com/coq/coq-opam-archive) (see the accompanying [Package Index](https://coq.inria.fr/opam/www/) or [that of coq.io](http://coq.io/opam/)). These make it easy to search contributed formalization packages and install them. There is also a curated list of Coq frameworks, libraries and tools in the [awesome-coq project](https://coq-community.org/awesome-coq/).

For **Isabelle/HOL** there is the [Archive of formal proofs](https://www.isa-afp.org) which has hundreds of contributions. You may browse [the index](https://www.isa-afp.org/topics.html) to get a feel for what is in there. And it is [growing rapidly](https://www.isa-afp.org/statistics.html), too.

Answer (score 12):

If you're interested in homotopy type theoretical foundations, I took a stab just today at comparing what's in the [various HoTT math libraries](https://github.com/glangmead/formalization/blob/main/survey.md).

It's a list of both theorems and "theories", since I was trying to understand the relative overall scope and overlap of the libraries. But it's not a particularly defensible collection of such theories, it's just a prototype.

The table links out to the repositories of the seven projects I was examining, but of special note is the Coq HoTT project which has a nice [table of contents](https://hott.github.io/HoTT/timing-html/toc.html).

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of the nice ToC generated by Coq HoTT! In your survey, you missed that we do have [Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces in Coq HoTT](https://hott.github.io/HoTT/timing-html/HoTT.Homotopy.EMSpace.html). Also, the Hurewicz theorem is wip in Coq HoTT, not Cubical Agda.

Comment: Thank you, Jarl. I've fixed those now.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the main theorem provers have central libraries of formal mathematics.
Here I've including their official statistics (accurate as of 2022-02-10) and more importantly a link to where you can find up-to-date statistics.

- [Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/) - [Archive of Formal Proofs (AFP)](https://www.isa-afp.org/) ([statistics](https://www.isa-afp.org/statistics.html))

  - 193,100 lemmas
  - 661 articles
  - 423 authors
  - 3,324,900 lines of code
- [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/) - [mathlib](https://leanprover-community.github.io/) ([statistics](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_stats.html))

  - 77,316 theorems
  - 32,040 definitions
  - 2,436 files
  - 221 contributors
  - 783,799 lines of code
- [Mizar](http://mizar.org/) - [Mizar Mathematical Library (MML)](http://mizar.org/library/) ([statistics](http://mmlquery.mizar.org/mmlquery/fillin.php?filledfilename=statistics.mqt))

  - 62,163 theorems
  - 12,840 definitions
  - 1,357 articles
  - 263 authors
- [Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/) - [set.mm](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmset.html) ([enumerated list)](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems.html)

  - 29,300 axioms, definitions, and theorems
- [HOL Light](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/hol-light/) - [HOL Light repo](https://github.com/jrh13/hol-light) (no statistics)
- [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) - [Coq Standard Library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/)

  - Unlike the others, Coq doesn't have a *central* mathematics library that I'm aware of, although it has [a lot of mathematics](https://project-awesome.org/coq-community/awesome-coq#type-theory-and-mathematics).  There are also no official statistics that I can find.

Comment: This older [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771711400100X) lists the HOL-Light main library as having 2,239 theorems and Flyspeck (which I'm not sure I'd consider a mathematical library in the same way as the others) as having 23,323 theorems.

Comment: This is a nice list! It's worth noting for nonexperts that each of these libraries differ in (a) how they count declarations and (b) what topics they include. For example, the Lean stats do not count meta declarations or "auto-generated" declarations like equational lemmas, constructors of inductive types, etc. The AFP contains many developments of formalized software and PL-focused topics that would not be found in the MML. One should be very cautious trying to compare systems with these statistics.

Comment: I think that counting theorems is completely meaningless here. What would be more interesting would be to have a list of interesting theorems with indications of where they are formalized, a bit like Freek's list but a lot more balanced and with a lot more theorems.

Comment: @PatrickMassot I won't way "completely meaningless", but I see your point.  However someone needs to implement such as list, get buy-in from all the other theorem proving communities, and keep it up-to-date for all the major libraries.  Right now most libraries only keep the above statistics and Freek's 100 theorem list.  I know Lean discussed some version 2.0 of Freek's list at some point. I think that would be a GREAT question on this site:  *What would version 2.0 of the "Formalizing 100 Theorems" list look like?*.  Do you want to ask it? :)

Comment: I'm afraid this will never happen because most proof assistants communities are simply not interested in proving math theorems. For instance you can go to the Coq zulip. You'll see they are working on lots of interesting stuff, but almost never discussing proving math theorems. Note this doesn't prevent having a couple of interested individuals in each community.

Comment: @JasonRute I think you spend too much time with Lean/mathlib people and have an extremely distorted view of the use of proof assistants. There are probably 1000 times more software verification than maths done in proof assistants. Also such a list would face the difficult question of what it means that a theorem is done. Does it count if you write a new library proving a theorem about real numbers using a definition of real numbers that is incompatible with all other libraries from your proof assistant? And what if it builds only with a ten years old version of Coq?

Comment: Ok, I [posted the question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/436/impact-of-formalizing-100-theorems-and-what-is-next) myself, but under the full humility that I may be vastly mistaken as to what is helpful for the community.  Hopefully, it will still generate some thoughtful answers.

Comment: @JasonRute I'm afraid I have to disagree with Patrick. You've done the best job I can find compiling the available figures. The criticisms above are apparent but hyperbolic and of limited value because of the lack of an alternative; you did the best that's publicly available after fixing a question of interest.

Answer (score 10):

From a similar [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3086/268) asked at cs.stackexchange.com.

Note: Only added info not already noted in existing answers.

- [Proofwiki](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- "Mizar Mathematical Library" [gigantic library](http://www.mizar.org/JFM/mmlident.html)
- A graph of the Mizar library (from 2012)

[image]

- [TPTP](http://www.tptp.org/) (Thousands of Problems for Theorem Provers)