# What are the major formal mathematics libraries and how big are they?

Tags: reference-request

Every major theorem prover has one or more libraries of general mathematics.  I'm curious where these libraries are and what their current statistics are (for example, how many theorems do they contain).

I know the following data **(and more importantly where to go to get the up-to-date statistics)**, but I'm hoping others can fill in the rest:

- Isabelle/HOL has [AFP](https://www.isa-afp.org) with currently [~192,200 theorems](https://www.isa-afp.org/statistics.html)
- [Lean 3](https://leanprover-community.github.io/) has the [mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib) library currently with [32,011 definitions and 77,227 theorems](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_stats.html)
- Mizar has the [MML](http://www.mizar.org/library/) with ???
- Metamath has [set.mm](https://github.com/metamath/set.mm) with ???
- [HOL-Light](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/hol-light/) has the [HOL-Light core library](https://github.com/jrh13/hol-light) with ???
- [HOL 4](https://hol-theorem-prover.org/) has ??? with ???
- [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) has ??? with ???
- Other major theorem prover(s) I'm neglecting have ??? with ???

Notes:

- I think I'm purposely leaving out projects like Flyspeck and the Four Color theorem since they are one-off projects which are not intended to be incorporated into a more general mathematical library (and I assume the useful lemmas have already been moved into a more main library).
- I am particularly uncertain how Coq fits in this picture since I have the impression (very possibly wrong) that Coq has many interconnected mathematical libraries, possibly with a lot of duplication.  But I do also think Coq has a [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/) as well.

## Update:

I found most of the statistics and posted them as [an answer to the linked question here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/141/where-can-i-find-lists-of-theorems-that-have-been-verified/315#315).

Comment: Related: [Where can I find lists of theorems that have been verified?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/141/where-can-i-find-lists-of-theorems-that-have-been-verified/)

Comment: Ok, it looks like the list of [Metamath theorems](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems.html) posted in the other question is indexed.  It seems there are 29,262 axioms/definitions/theorems and 42,542 total if you also count the math boxes (which I think is where users store their in progress work).

Comment: I'm voting to close as a dup of [Where can I find lists of theorems that have been verified?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/141/where-can-i-find-lists-of-theorems-that-have-been-verified).

Perhaps you could add your findings there as a new answer and we may hope that further ones will have the info you ask for.

Comment: If we must.  But what I’m most interested in is the theorem counts of the math libraries (and where to find up to date data).  It doesn’t seem that that other question addresses that.  Maybe I need to ask a better worded question, or maybe this information just doesn’t exist outside of looking at the raw data found in the answers to the other question.

Comment: Since the other question is community wiki, I think it would be fine to edit the question/answers to also include counts.

Comment: @hardmath Fair points, but 2 nitpicks:  (1) It is not obvious the Mizar is larger than say AFP or mathlib.  (2) I think most of the major players in the theorem proving game do have large centralized math libraries including Isabelle, Mizar, Lean, and Metamath.  Coq seems to be the main exception as I can see.